# Get enum variable in jpql

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm trying to get the status variable from this enum :

```
public enum Topic {

    NotPublished(100),
    Published(101);

    public final Integer status ;

    Topic(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    } 
}
```

On this JPQL

```
   @Query("SELECT com...UserDTO(u.id, u.name)" +
            "FROM UserJpa u LEFT JOIN TopicJpa p ON u.id=p.user.id " +
            "AND p.isPublished=com...Topic.Published.status" +
            "GROUP BY u.id , u.name")
    List<UserDTO> findUsers();
```

But I can't reach to status

Note : p.isPublished is Integer

Comment: show us you enities

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I solve the issue by declare new parameter in repo like this:
Integer TopicPublished = Topic.Published.status;
then I use this parameter like this:
com....repositories.UserRepository.TopicPublished